# wxWidgets - `wxTimer` to update a function every second

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am trying to make a music application using `wxWidgets`, I'm very new to `wxWidgets` and C++ as well, I made a function that should update the elapsed time, when the user plays the song, so the seek bar, and digital clock, updates with song position, every second. I have set up the `wxTimer` like this

```
    timer = new wxTimer(this);
    timer->Bind(wxEVT_TIMER, &Frame::UpdateElapsedTime, this);
```

and the function that starts the timer is

```
void Frame::Play(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    stopped = false;

    int songIndex = 0;

    std::string Song;
    wxString wxSong;

    songIndex = playlistBox->GetSelection();
    wxSong = playlistBox->GetString(songIndex);

    Song = std::string(wxSong);
    Song = "/home/apoorv/Music/mod/" + Song;

    std::cout << "wxString: " << wxSong << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Song: " << Song << std::endl;

    mediaCtrl->Load(Song);
    mediaCtrl->Play();

    timer->Start(1000);
}
```

and the function that I want to update every second is

```
void Frame::UpdateElapsedTime(wxTimerEvent& event)
{

    wxLogMessage("OnTimer called.");

    seekBar->SetValue(mediaCtrl->Tell());
    seekBar->SetMax(mediaCtrl->Length());

    std::string SongTime = std::to_string(mediaCtrl->Tell() / 60000) + ":" + std::to_string(mediaCtrl->Tell() / 1000)
        + "/" + std::to_string(mediaCtrl->Length() / 60000) + ":" + std::to_string(mediaCtrl->Length() / 1000);

    staticText->SetLabel(SongTime);
}
```

It compiles fine, but nothing happens. I was doing similar thing, when I used `wxPython` before this, and it worked.

Comment: Do you get the log messages on the console?

Comment: I assume that the `Play` function is executed? And that the `timer` you show being created is the same `timer` in the `Play` function?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev No, I don't get any log message on the console.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I wanted the `UpdateElapsedTime()` to run every second when the user presses play. So that the song time updates every second.

Comment: Well, you have some log messages in `Play()`. If you are not seeing them, is the `Play()` method even called when you press tha button? Can you set a breakpoint inside it and see what happens?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev My bad, I thought you are asking about, if I get some errors for the timer not working, Yes the log messages, in the `Play()` `wxString` and `Song` prints fine on the console.

Comment: @apoorv569 Could you try calling `Bind()` on `this`, instead of on `timer`?

Comment: I tried this `this->Bind(wxEVT_TIMER, &Frame::UpdateElapsedTime, this);`
But as soon as I press play, the app freezes. Song keeps playing though.

Comment: What is `mediaCtrl`? What does its `Play` function do? Perhaps that function is *blocking* (i.e. not returning until the song is finished)? Maybe the `mediaCtrl` object have the functionality you want already built-in?

Comment: `mediaCtrl` is `wxMediaCtrl` that handles media files, both audio and video.

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_media_ctrl.html

Comment: Try adding some logging after the `Play` call to see if and when it returns. If it doesn't return immediately then it's synchronous and block until the song is finished, and you have to figure out a way to make it asynchronous.

Comment: @apoorv569, are you creating the play button and controls yourself and not calling `ShowPlayerControls()`?

Comment: @Igor Yes, I have different buttons for play, pause, next, previous, and stop, all binded separately using the `Bind()`, and `wxMediaCtrl` handles audio part. I didn't understand `ShowPlayerControls()` properly so I didn't use it.

Comment: @apoorv569, this function will use the internal controls of the player. Build and run the media sample - it shows what it does. Basically you underlying player already has all those controls. You just need to show them with this call. Problem is - not all players have them. See if you can display the internal ones and if not - create them yourself. Also, a bit of a suggestion - if you don't understand something in wx, try the sample. If its still not clear - try it in.

Comment: @Igor Reading on the documentation, it looks like `ShowPlayerControls()` only works for Quicktime and Directshow backends, I am using Gstreamer, as I am on Linux. https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_media_ctrl.html#aeb677324f81580e7647c70b332395012

Comment: @apoorv569, did you try it? What version of GStreamer do you use?

Comment: I did, I added `ShowPlayerControls()` in my `Play()`, it compiled fine, but when I press play, nothings shows up. I should be on the latest version, as I am on Arch, its 1.18.0-1.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev I tried again, `Bind()` on `this` instead of `timer`, I think I mis-typed something before, it did update, but only updated the first second, then it stopped.

Comment: Is there any chance that something is calling `timer->Stop()`? If for example your "Stop" button is doing this, can you check whether its handler is somehow being called (by accident or not)?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev Yes, I checked, there was a if else statement in `UpdateElapsedTime()` to check if timer is running then stop if not then start, I removed it, it now updates  every second. I am also able to seek through the song time with the slider widget. Thank you. :D

Comment: By the way, if I want to move all the functions associated with all the widgets, to a separate file, do I have to make all widgets declaration `static`. Like I wanna make one file for the base GUI, and another file for the all the functions/events, and so on. I tried moving the functions to different file, but it complains about `invalid use of non-static data member`.

Comment: @apoorv569 I'm glad the problem has been fixed. As for moving the functions, it might probably be better to post it as another question, as this one is already getting too long with comments.In general, though, it is a bad idea to make your widgets static, so first think/search for other ways to split out code.